# Importing CSV into .sdf in SQL Server Compact Edition, creating query

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am trying to import a `.csv` file into an `.sdf` database file, and I was trying to use SQLCEToolbox.

The query that tool created looks fine to me, but when it comes to "execute" something goes wrong. The query contains as many inserts as needed, but for some reason it adds to the table more rows than needed.

To check what is wrong, I wrote simple code in c#.

What I was trying to execute looked like this (it is part of the query created with toolbox):

```
INSERT INTO [table] ([column1], [column2], [dataTimeColumn]) 
VALUES (N'var', N'var2', {ts 'yyyymmdd hhmmss'})
```

When it comes to executing one query, there are no exceptions, but with two inserts there is "error parsing the query".

I assume that the problem is with the data format, this yyyymmdd(date) hhmmss(time), but I don't know why and how to correct it. Both, date and time, must be in the table in this format. Could anyone help?

Comment: As far as I know, SQL Server CE doesn't support multiple statements in a single command execution

Comment: How about the toolbox? I assume it was made to solve this problem

Comment: The Toolbox seperates queries split with GO, yes

Comment: Please provide a sample database create table, and csv file, use sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com to report your issue, thanks